# Getting 401 unauthorised when calling calendar api of office 365

Tags: json, api, azure, outlook, office365

I am trying to access the office 365 calendar api to create an event. The steps i followed are

1. Created app and registered it in azure
2. Gave permisissions to the app
3. Hitting `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantid}}/oauth2/token` to get the access token

body :

```
{
 "grant_type":"client_credentials",
 "client_id": "*****",
 "client_secret": "****",
 "resource":"https://outlook.office.com"
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "262800",
    "expires_on": "1532026206",
    "not_before": "1532022306",
    "resource": "https://outlook.office.com",
    "access_token":"******"
}
```

When i pass this access token to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events` which creates events. it gives me 401 unauthorised. Body of the request is as shown below. Someone please assist.

```
{
  "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": {
      "DateTime": "2019-02-02T18:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "End": {
      "DateTime": "2019-02-02T19:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "arulvelug@hexabot.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Name": "Arulvelu G"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure do you have enough permissions? It looks like you need `https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read` reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#minimum-required-scope-1

Comment: HI Jayendran , Can you please assist in detail

Comment: If you look through the document which I shared above mentioned about the scope you need to access `https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read` i.e, You need to have the scope for reading the calendars

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do authorization of office 365 and use REST API via Postman, here is a solution for your reference:

**First: get security Token**

Access [https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf] via Http Post method. The content of the http request is as follows.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
  xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"  
  xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity- 
utility-1.0.xsd">  
<s:Header>  
<a:Action 
s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>  
<a:ReplyTo>  
  <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>  
</a:ReplyTo>  
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>  
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"  
   xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">  
<o:UsernameToken>  
    <o:Username>[username]</o:Username>  
    <o:Password>[password]</o:Password>  
</o:UsernameToken>  
</o:Security>  
</s:Header>  
<s:Body>  
<t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">  
  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">  
    <a:EndpointReference>  
    <a:Address>[endpoint]</a:Address>  
</a:EndpointReference>  
</wsp:AppliesTo>  
<t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>  
<t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>  
<t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>  
</t:RequestSecurityToken>  
</s:Body>  
</s:Envelope>
```

The demonstration screenshot in Postman:

[image]

And the response content will include a security token as below, we can use this security token to get Access Token of office 365.

[image]

**Second: get Access Token**

Here i show you how to get access token, I get it of my SharePoint using the security token.

Access [https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0] via http Post method. The content of the request is the security token that we have got above as below.

[image]

And the response as below:

[image]

We can see that there are two cookie, rtFa and FedAuth in response header, and these two cookie need to be added to the request in subsequent request.

**Third: get Request Digest**

Access [https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo] via http Post method with that two cookies which we have got above.

[image]

And the response as below:

[image]

This is the final Token we want!

Then we can use REST API of our app in O365, like SharePoint , we only need to add this token and the previous two cookie, as shown in the following figure.

[image]